# How to display embedded text file in Excel cell using python

Tags: python, win32com

I have embedded text (document) file into `Excel` cell, but it's displayed as a `big icon`, which occupies too much space. How can I change icon into a hyperlink lookalike name fitting the cell?

I have an `Excel` file `text.xlsx`. I have embedded a file `profile.docx` in cell `B3`. The following code does that -

```
import win32com.client as win32
sourceFile = r'E:\test.xlsx'
fileToEmbed = r'E:\profile.docx'
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(sourceFile)
ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
dest_cell = ws.Range("B3") #change to your wanted location
obj = ws.OLEObjects()
wordpath = 'C\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office 14\\WINWORD.EXE'
obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename=fileToEmbed,Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=True, IconFileName=wordpath,IconIndex=0,IconLabel='Profile.docx',Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=1,Height=1)
wb.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

On the left hand side is what I get, and on right hand side is what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the file manually on the right picture?
It looks like a Hyperlink, not an embedded file. Using embedding manually (through the Excel GUI) I cannot get it to look like that at all. So what you are asking might be impossible.

Comment: I added that link manually, just to demonstrate. All I want is the embedded file's icon should fit into the cell because I have to add embedded file in column `B` for each of the 1000 rows. With such big icon, extending/overlapping on many rows downwards, it will become too cumbersome. Hyperlink (which fits into the cell vertically) was just to demonstrate. If you have any ideas to achieve that, kindly let me know.

Comment: Thats what I mean: If you cannot reproduce this manually for just one item, I am afraid Excel simply lacks the functionality to draw the icons any smaller. 
From my experiments, the embedded items aren't even bound to a cell. The cell you defined simply is the startpoint of the drawing for the oject. The object itself lies above the spreadsheet and can be moved by drag and drop above the actual sheet. It seems what you want Excel to do simply isnt possible :(

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. Will try to see if there is a way out. Many thanks for your insight.